# Extraer los datos de la columna coment para ponerlo en el encabezado de la tabla php

Tags: php, html, sql, tabla-dinámica

Estoy haciendo una tabla dinámica recogiendo los datos necesarios de la BD con bucles. No obstante, no se como extraer los datos de la columna comment (en donde tengo el nombre de cada columna) y colocarlo como nombre en el encabezado de las columnas de mi tabla html.

Por el momento solo tengo los datos de la tabla:

```
include("connect.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conexion)) {echo "MySQL conn. err:".mysqli_connect_error();}
//consulta comentarios de la tabla
 $sql = "SELECT column_comment FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'tbl_moble';";
//consulta datos tabla
 $sql2 = "select * from tbl_moble";
 $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);

 while(($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))){


if($result['column_comment'])

  {

echo "<table width='50%' border='1'><tr>";
  $CurCol = $result['column_comment'];
  foreach ($result as $head)
      {

        echo "<th align='center'>". $head . "</th>";

      }
  }
 else
  {
  $CurCol = "No text stored";
  } 
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($rows as $data)
      {
        echo "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>";
      } 

    }
    echo "</table>";
 }
 ?>
```

Edito: He cambiado el codigo. Hasta donde he podido llegar, he conseguido extraer los comments de la base de datos. Y ahora al ejecutarlo solo pone la primera columna con el encabezado el resto de valores $header los pone despues de la tabla y una vez ya mostrado todos los datos contenidos en la tabla.

Aclarar que se trata de un ejercicio. No os alarméis, estoy aprendiendo xD.
Adjunto imagen tras ejecutar el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, la información que quieres está en la variable `$data`? Puedes obtener el dato haciendo algo como `echo $data["comment"];`

Comment: Pero ¿en serio que quieres sacar datos de `information_schema` para mostrarlos en tu programa? ¿por qué quieres hacer eso? ¿es un programa sobre cursos de lenguaje SQL o algo así? No conviene estar manipulando datos de `information_schema` para mostrarlos al usuario final.

Comment: Hola @A. Cedan. Veras en la base de datos hay una columna de comentarios accesible mediante la consulta:   `SELECT column_comment FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'tbl_mueble' ` La cual devuelve la siguiente lista de datos:  column_comment Clave primaria nombre mueble altura mueble ancho mueble hondo mueble FK` Necesito esos datos como cabecera en la tabla que muestro mediante el codigo php del principio, el cual es solo para mostrar los datos contenidos en la tabla mediante $data. Ahora lo que quiero es colocar los encabezados sobr dicha tabla aunque no se como.

Comment: @ A. Cedano XD. Pues si es un curso de sql la verdad. La cosa es que debajo de cada nombre de columna hay un comentario con el nombre que se debe mostrar que es el que se añadió mediante la instrucción: ``id_fabricant` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Clave primaria',`` (por poner un ejemplo) y quiero extraer ese comment en php para ponerlo como cabecera en una tabla. No se si existen mas formas de hacerlo..

Comment: A ver, no es buena idea extraer o mostrar información interna de las tablas, mi pregunta era en el sentido de si se trataba de una aplicación destinada a enseñar el funcionamiento interno de la base de datos porque sería, a mi juicio, lo único que justifique tu proceder. Si se trata de datos normales, para mostrar a usuarios cualesquiera, no es justificado estar accediendo a `information_schema` cuando en el mismo `SELECT` ya tienes los nombres de las columnas. No sé si me explico. Tu pregunta tampoco es que sea muy clara y por eso no puedo ofrecerte una ayuda más concreta.

Comment: @A. Cedano. Bueno pues a ver si ahora esta algo mejor al menos para ser entendible (hago lo que puedo)